# The process for tag protocol died unexpectedly

Tags: linux, arch-linux, daemon, dolphin, garuda-linux

IDK why but my Arch-based garuda OS throw an error all the time:

```
kf.kio.core: "The process for the tags protocol died unexpectedly."
kf.kio.core: "The process for the tags protocol died unexpectedly."
```

I get this exact error in dolphin as well as timeshift (might be other application as well)

Note: I recently install telegram-desktop form snap. and (also I start TeamViewer daemon today but it's closed now, I don't think this is the case here.)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

This solved it, from https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=253032:

> Got it, thank you so much. I knew that is something related to baloo and indexing but totally forgot to reset DB.

> Delete folder ~/.local/share/baloo/ solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following helped me.

```
rm -r ~/.local/share/baloo/
```

Comment: This appears to be the solution, based on the link in the other answer, but someone downvoted it, probably because it lacks explanation. The term "baloo' doesn't appear in the question and removing apparently random files could be seen as risky.

Comment: This was a tricky situation since the other answer didn't contain any actual fixes, only a link. If that link helped you, the correct Stack Exchange response would have been to submit an edit (as I just did) to that question to list the required steps.